# Javascript HierarchyRequestError

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

FF JS interpreter does not like this code:

```
var dialog = "<div id=\"dialog\" title=\"Dimensions\"><p>new width = " + r[0] + "mm</p><p>new height = " + r[1] + "mm</p></div>";
$("body").append(dialog).dialog({ resizeable:false, modal:true, buttons:{"OK":function(){ $(this).dialog("close"); }} });
```

Why is this problematic?

> HierarchyRequestError: Node cannot be inserted at the specified point
>   in the hierarchy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be because `$("body").append(dialog)` returns the body and not the appended element and `$("body").append(dialog).dialog({...});` is trying to call **.dialog** on the body?

Try separating the calls to:

```
$("body").append(dialog);
$('#dialog').dialog({ resizeable:false, modal:true, buttons:{"OK":function(){$(this).dialog("close"); }}});
```

Comment: That's a good point. `.dialog` should be applied to the appended child.